# Volume of a convex body

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation

Let $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define the linear forms $L_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}x_j$ where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. Define the domain $C$ by $$C : \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |L_i(x)|\le \lambda_i, \quad \lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}, \quad 1 \le i \le n\}.$$ I am told that $\text{vol}(C/2) = \frac{\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n}{|\det A|}$, where $A = (a_{ij})$. I know that a linear change of variables is needed to bring in $\det A$ but I am not sure about the exact line of reasoning. Could someone please explain the details?